# Posix Thread - (mutex and condition variable) issue,

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex

Below is the code which i am trying for producer consumer problem using posix threads.
In my code I am using condition variable to wait and signal mutex. My code allows me to configure number of producer and consumer threads.

But when consumer thread count is more than producer thread count, my program hangs and do not finish.

I think, producer thread function has completed before consumer thread functions by putting max values in queue. And waiting consumer threads are not receiving signal. Although before completion producer thread has generated signal for each value it added to the queue.

Need help to identify issue in code, so that it runs for any combination of producer and consumer thread count.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
#include<pthread.h>

using namespace std;

pthread_cond_t c=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t m=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

long max_item=50000;
long produced=0;
long consumed=0;

const long producer_count=5;
const long consumer_count=15;

queue<long>q;

void * producer(void *)
{
    long i=1;
    while(true)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
        if(produced==max_item)
        {pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);break;} 

        q.push(i++);++produced;
        pthread_cond_signal(&c);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    cout<<"Producer produced:"<<i-1<<endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);

}
void *consumer(void *)
{
    long i=1;
    long val=0;
    while(true)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
        if(consumed==max_item){pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);break;}    
        while(q.empty())
           {pthread_cond_wait(&c,&m);}
        val=q.front();q.pop();
        ++i,consumed++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    cout<<"Consumer consumed:"<<i-1<<endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
}
int main()
{
   pthread_t p[producer_count],c[consumer_count];

   for(int i=0;i<producer_count;++i)
    pthread_create(&p[i],NULL,producer,NULL);

   for(int i=0;i<consumer_count;++i)
    pthread_create(&c[i],NULL,consumer,NULL);

   for(int i=0;i<producer_count;++i)
    pthread_join(p[i],NULL);

   for(int i=0;i<consumer_count;++i)
    pthread_join(c[i],NULL);

   cout<<"Total produced:"<<produced<<endl;
   cout<<"Total consumed:"<<consumed<<endl;
   cout<<"Queue size at end:"<<q.size()<<endl;

   pthread_mutex_destroy(&m);
    return 0;
}


Output:
$ ./a.out
Producer produced:12740
Consumer consumed:3351
Producer produced:16948
Consumer consumed:2512
Consumer consumed:3383
Producer produced:4892
Producer produced:7417
Consumer consumed:5374
Consumer consumed:4550
Producer produced:8003
Consumer consumed:5229
Consumer consumed:2023
Consumer consumed:1366
Consumer consumed:3346
Consumer consumed:2231

--Program hangs here-----


Output from different run when both producer and consumer thread count are set to 15.
$ ./a.out
Producer produced:1276
Producer produced:2162
Producer produced:1401
Producer produced:505
Producer produced:455
Producer produced:1900
Producer produced:2522
Producer produced:901
Producer produced:308
Producer produced:1461
Producer produced:755
Producer produced:102
Producer produced:21332
Consumer consumed:514
Consumer consumed:1335
Consumer consumed:4219
Consumer consumed:1422
Consumer consumed:644
Consumer consumed:231
Producer produced:14191
Consumer consumed:621
Consumer consumed:541
Consumer consumed:1505
Consumer consumed:32234
Consumer consumed:1985
Producer produced:729
Consumer consumed:2723
Consumer consumed:1012
Consumer consumed:69
Consumer consumed:945
Total produced:50000
Total consumed:50000
Queue size at end:0

---Program completes here after showing produced and consumed count are equal and queue is fully consumed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consumer loops until it gets all the produced items, but with more consumers, the items get divided, so you need another check to see when the consumer has finished.  The producer could set a finished boolean and signal that with the same condition variable with pthread_cond_broadcast, so the consumers should check that within the locked mutex before waiting on the empty queue.

Comment: In consumer thread just after locking mutex, code checks if (consumed==max_item) ie all values are consumed from queue. If not pick a value from queue, if queue is empty then issue wait condition. As consumed==max_item is just after mutex lock, it should return true if all items are consumed and break from loop after unlocking mutex.

Comment: Consumed will never be max_item, because the items are divided over the consumers, so the consumers will be waiting on an empty queue

Comment: It seems I have given wrong name to variable, I checked in code, (i) is local count variable to the consumer thread and (consumed) is global count  used by all consumer threads. As (consumed) is accessed and checked in mutex, first line after lock it should break while loop when consumed(total from all consumer) is equal to max_item and consumer thread should not go to next step(ie wait as queue is empty).

Comment: Even so, only 1 consumer will receive the last and return, the others will wait on an empty queue.

Comment: Yes, I understand the issue with you last comment and I can relate your first comment also now. So I made changes for waiting check(while loop - instead of checking q.empty(), I have to check if all items are consumed or not using consumed variable. q.empty() check will work on single consumer thread only. But I got into one issue, my producer threads completed before consumer.and some consumer thread were still in wait and program did not completed so I removed wait and signal and used completed check in consumers. Thanks.

Comment: Better solution as per you first comment, will use broadcast. Hence my waiting consumer(still waiting after all values from queue are consumed) threads will wake up finish.

Comment: The producer setting a ready flag might be a more general solution, but checking if all items are consumed before checking whether whether the queue is empty is indeed a fitting solution here.